# How do I most concisely access the parameters of an Action (or Func) property?

Tags: c#, lambda, properties

I'm amazed I couldn't find an answer to this question on stackoverflow or MSDN.  I strongly suspect my search skills are the gap here, but I'll risk asking anyways.  I've looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138249/3367144) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4597222/3367144) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3587659/3367144) here on stackoverflow.  None of them are directly questions or answers to what I'm asking, but they are tangentially related enough that I hoped to glean answers from them anyways.  But no luck!  Anyways, here's the question!

---

When I define an interface which declares an `Action<int, int>` property

```
public interface ICoordinateProcessor {
    System.Action<int, int> onTwoIntegers { get; }
}
```

It can easily be implemented with a null-returning lambda taking two integers as parameters

```
public class RealCoordinateProcessor : ICoordinateProcessor {
    public override Action<int, int> onTwoIntegers {
        get {
            return (x, y) => this.someInternalState = x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

Easy peasy!  But when I use roslyn to autocomplete the interface, it fills in the following:

```
public class RealCoordinateProcessor : ICoordinateProcessor {
    public override Action<int, int> onTwoIntegers => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

That compiles with no errors or warnings, and is also very concise syntax that I have never seen and would prefer to use.  **How do I use that much tighter syntax to have the same effect as my second snippet above?**

Or equivalently, **how do I access the parameters of the lambda in that third snippet?**  When I try this:

```
public override Action<int, int> onTwoIntegers (x, y) => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

The compiler freaks out because I obviously don't know what I'm doing.  But I'm not sure what else to try, and I'm not sure how to search for examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, in C#6 with Roslyn you can use **[Expression Bodied Function Members](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodied-function-members)**:

```
public override Action<int,int> onTwoIntegers => (x,y) => { };
```

In generally, it's not so much different with delegate-lambda syntax:

```
var onTwoIntegersClass = new RealCoordinateProcessor().onTwoIntegers;
Action<int,int> onTwoIntegersVar = (x,y)=>{};
Delegate.Combine(onTwoIntegersVar, onTwoIntegersClass);
```

Comment: Interesting.  So all I was missing was an extra `=>` between `onTwoIntegers` and `(x, y)` in my naive attempt to appease the compiler.  I just tried that and it works.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for @TckS, i lost one symbol)